# Confusion about a proof of every irreducible polynomial has a root in a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I am here not for the proof of this theorem, so this is not a duplicate.

Here are the theorem and the proof:
[image]

I can follow the first few steps of the proof (prove that the quotient is a field, the image of $F$ is isomorphic to $F$), but I couldn't understand how the author gets the natural projection "out of the polynomial". In my understanding,
$p(\pi(x))=\sum a_n(\pi(x))^n$ and $\pi(p(x))=\sum \pi(a_n)\left(\pi(x)\right)^n$. Why is $\pi(a_n)=a_n$ true?

My guess is that the author says he "*identifies $F$ with its image in $K$*". Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $V \subseteq W$ are two abelian groups, then the canonical projection $V \to V/W$ is the map taking $v \in V$ to the coset $v + W$. Since the composition $F \to F[x] \to K$ is a nonzero map of fields, it is injective, hence we can view any scalar $a \in F$ in the target ring $\overline{a} \in K$: I think going between $a$ and $\overline{a}$ is what you’re missing.

Comment: I'm confused about your confusion. As you yourself quote, the author identified $F$ with its image in $K$. Under that identification, $\pi(a_n) = a_n$.

Comment: @YourongZang $\pi (a_n)=\overline a_n$. Usually, $\pi $ is not injective. But since $F $ and $K $ are fields, $\varphi=\pi|_F $ is injective. Now by first isomorphism theorem, $\varphi (F)\approx K $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is completely correct.

The thing is that the restriction of $\pi$ to $F$ is an injection (so an embedding of fields), therefore we identify elements of $K$ with their image in $F$ under $\pi$.

That's what "have a root in a bigger field" means in any case if you allow field embeddings instead of strict inclusion.

Another way to see it is that the map $\pi_{\mid F} : F\to K$ makes $K$ into an $F$-algebra, and the definition of this $F$-algebra structure is $\lambda \cdot v := \pi(\lambda)v, \lambda \in F, v\in K$; in particular by definition $a_n(\pi(x))^n = \pi(a_n)(\pi(x))^n$ (in fact you can see that this is the only sensible way of giving the expression $a_n(\pi(x))^n$ any meaning in the first place ! or more generally of giving the expression $p(\pi(x))$ any meaning)